# Fastest way to add a value in the middle of a sorted array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a sorted array, lets say D={1,2,3,4,5,6} and I want to add the number 5 in the middle. I can do that by adding the value 5 in the middle and move the other values one step to the right.

The problem is that I have an array with 1000 length and I need to do that operation 10.000 times, so I need a faster way.

What options do I have? Can I use LinkedLists for better performance?

Comment: definitely you should use `LinkedList` or similar data structure  in these type of case.

Comment: This sounds like a Yes or No question. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: If you always add to the middle, then a `LinkedList` would probably be faster due to the fact you'd avoid copying all the element references around on inserts (or even growing the underlying array).

If it's performance critical, benchmark it and read up on [JVM micro-benchmarking](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks) before.

Also if you are always adding to the middle, it would probably be possible to solve this using multiple collections that you concatenate when you need the final result (but my understanding of what you are doing is quite limited :-)).

Comment: I wont add always in the middle.

Comment: I'd still go with a `LinkedList` - ignore that last sentence in that case.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you add said numbers. If only in ascending or descending order - then yes, `LinkedList` will do the trick, but only if you keep the node reference in between inserts.

If you're adding numbers in arbitrary order, you may want to deconstruct your array, add the new entries and reconstruct it again. This way you can use a data structure that's good at adding and removing entries while maintaining "sortedness". You have to relax one of your assumptions however.

**Option 1**
Assuming you don't need constant time random access while adding numbers:

Use a binary sorted tree.

The downside - while you're adding, you cannot read or reference an element by their position, not easily at least. Best case scenario - you're using a tree that keeps track of how many elements the left node has and can get the `i`th element in `log(n)` time. You can still get pretty good performance if you're just iterating through the elements though.

Total runtime is down to `n * log(n)` from `n^2`. Random access is `log(n)`.

**Option 2**
Assuming you don't need the elements sorted while you're adding them.

Use a normal array, but add elements to the end of it, then sort it all when you're done.

Total runtime: `n * log(n)`. Random access is `O(1)`, however elements are not sorted.

**Option 3**
(This is kinda cheating, but...)
If you have a limited number of values, then employing the idea of `BucketSort` will help you achieve great performance. Essentially - you would replace your array with a sorted map.

Runtime is `O(n)`, random access is `O(1)`, but it's only applicable to a very small number of situations.

**TL;DR**
Getting arbitrary values, quick adding and constant-time positional access, while maintaining sortedness is difficult. I don't know any such structure. You have to relax *some* assumption to have room for optimizations.

Comment: If I have a Linked List with N objects and I want to add an object in k position (k<N), then I have to do k steps to finds the position and add the value?

Comment: Yeah, hence, unless you have some kind of "shortcut" to the value, it will be just as bad as an array.

Comment: What kind of shortcut?

Comment: Like I said - a pointer to the node for example. The stock `LinkedList` in the standard libraries does not expose such functionality however.

Comment: No it is not, it's only an integer. A pointer can be trivially made from it for an *array* (and hence `ArrayList`), but not for a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

A `LinkedList` will probably not help you very much, if at all. Basically you are exchanging the cost of shifting every value on insert with the cost of having to traverse each node in order to reach the insertion point.

This traversal cost will also need to be paid whenever accessing each node. A `LinkedList` shines as a queue, but if you need to access the internal nodes individually it's not a great choice.

In your case, you want a sorted Tree of some sort. A BST (Balanced Search Tree, also referred to as a Sorted Binary Tree) is one of the simplest types and is probably a good place to start.

A good option is a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), which is likely functionally equivalent to how you were using an array, if you simply need to keep track of a set of sorted numbers.